# Can my code determine the creation date for the current user's account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

If an admin has created a user account in the Firebase Console, after this user has signed in, is it possible to retrieve the 'created' date of the user?

PS Big vote for Firebase to add more admin controls programmatically, for user management.

Comment: You tagged with [firebase-database], but I don't see how this is related. Can you update to make the relation more clear or remove that tag?

Comment: Hi Frank, I didn't actually put these tags on, I believe a mod must have adjusted them to this. I would say a large part of Firebase user management is part of the database though, Firebase themselves suggest that user records beyond an email and password should be stored for example at a /users node.

Comment: Hi Josh. We are taking internally your vote for adding more programmatic admin controls :)

Comment: It's possible now with `Auth.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationDate`

Answer (score 18):

On the **Firebase client web API** you can get the user's account creation date with:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var signupDate = new Date(user.metadata.creationTime);
```

Link to unhelpful [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata).

Comment: Is this code standard ECMAScript, or does it depend on implementation-specific functionality? From [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#date_time_string_format), it seems that the only standard format supported by `new Date` / `Date.parse` is a simplification of ISO 8601, e.g. `2011-10-10T14:48:00`. Firebase Auth time is in "UTC Date string" form e. g. `Sat, 03 Feb 2001 04:05:06 GMT`.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Good point. I've tested that this works in recent versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge. But you could use a third-party date parser if necessary.

Comment: BTW, there is also a completely undocumented `a` parameter that is a unix timestamp. So you can use: `(new Date(parseInt(user.metadata.a))` However, relying on an undocumented property in the Firebase payload seemed much riskier than using long-standing date parsing capabilities that just aren't technically in the standards.

Comment: I agree with you. On the other hand, the mentioned capabilities aren't just missing in the standard; I haven't found a single piece of documentation (even implementation-provided) that proves that such format is supported... Like you suggested, I ended up using third party library.

Answer (score 12):

Currently AFAIK, getting creation date is only possible with the Admin Node.js SDK:

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log("Creation time:", userRecord.metadata.creationTime);
  });
```

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.usermetadata.md#usermetadatacreationtime

Comment: how to convert the UTC timestamp to local timestamp for creationTime?

Comment: Documentation is updated. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#get_user . In python just go with `_` everywhere (`user.user_medadata.creation_timestamp`)

Answer (score 8):

## Admin backend SDK

This is now achievable with the following in case you are trying to get the info on a server side application.

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(user => {
    console.log(user.metadata.creationTime);
});
```

## Client side Applications

Despite you are able to see this information on firebase Auth console you wont be able to retrieve this data on the application side as you can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user).

If you want to use this data on your application you'll need to store it under your database on somethink like `databaseRoot/user/userUid/createdAt`. So make sure you are creating this node whenever creating a new user such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927186/swift-firebase-how-to-store-more-user-data-other-than-email-and-password/37927748#37927748).

Comment: how to convert the UTC timestamp to local timestamp for creationTime?

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, Angularfire2 is at release candidate version 5. The Javascript API makes it possible to retrieve both the creation date and the last login date of the [currently authenticated user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata.html).

Example:

```
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  const createdAt = user.metadata.creationTime
  const lastLogin = user.metadata.lastSignInTime
  const a = user.metadata['a'] // <- Typescript does not allow '.' operator
  const b = user.metadata['b'] // <- Typescript does not allow '.' operator

  console.log(`${ user.email } was created ${ createdAt } (${ a }).`)
  console.log(`${ user.email } last logged in ${ lastLogin } (${ b }).`)
})
```

Though not listed as formal properties, `a` and `b` yield the `Date` objects for the creation and last login dates, respectively, while `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` are the same as GMT string values.

Answer (score 2):

This function will iterate through all of your users and record there creationDate under the `users/$uid/company` location

```
const iterateAllUsers = function () {
  const prom = db.ref('/users').once('value').then(
    (snap) => {
      const promArray = [];
      const users = snap.val();

      Object.keys(users).forEach((user) => {
        promArray.push(getUIDCreationDate(user));
      });
      return Promise.all(promArray);
    });
  return prom;
}

const getUIDCreationDate = function (uid) {

  const prom = fb.getUser(uid)
    .then(function (userRecord) {
      const prom2 = db.ref(`/users/${uid}/company`).update({ creationDate: userRecord.metadata.createdAt }).then((success) => console.log(success)).catch((error) => console.log(error));
      return prom2;
    }).catch(
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
    });
  return prom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of getting it... 
When you get a firebase.User - usually from some code such as:

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()).then(
  (userCredential) => {//do something with user - notice that this is a user credential.
});
```

anyways, inside this userCredential there is the user
and if you do

```
let myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userCredential.user);
```

you are going to see that you can access the createdAt field

```
myObj.createdAt // somenumber = time in miliseconds since 1970
```

So to access it

```
let myDate: Date = new Date();
myDate.setTime(+myObj.createdAt); //the + is important, to make sure it converts to number
console.log("CREATED AT = " + myDate.toString() );
```

VOILA!

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug 2021, console.dir(user) gives:

```
    {
"uid": "2Sf.......PH2",
"anonymous": true,
"isAnonymous": true,
"providers": [],
"photoURL": null,
"email": null,
"emailVerified": false,
"displayName": null,
"phoneNumber": null,
"refreshToken": "ACz.......7tgTs",
"metadata": {
"creationTimestamp": "2020-07-08T18:32:09.701Z",
"lastSignInTimestamp": "2020-07-08T18:32:09.701Z"
}
}
```

So, `user.metadata.creationTimestamp` will give the creation date.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function for my Xamarin Android project to get the date and time which worked for me:

```
   public DateTime GetCurrentUserCreatedDate()
    {
        var metadata = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Metadata;
        var creationTimestamp = metadata?.CreationTimestamp;
        var creationDate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(creationTimestamp.Value / 1000).DateTime;
        return creationDate;
    }
```